# Lookup that returns cell data with hyperlink formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When using lookup the returned data is in plain text, however, the data in the cell that has been looked up is a hyperlink. I would like the hyperlink to come through with the lookup as well so as not to go through every result and create the hyperlink again.